# Is there a reasonable way to transform a native android app to a progressive web app?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, native

I have an native android app which i want to transform into a progressive web app.
Was looking for a tool for such a transformation online but didn't really find something.

One way would be to build the whole application from scratch (or almost from scratch) again...

But is there a way to automate the transformation of an existing android app into a progressive web app? I thought there might be tools to transform the xml-Files and Java-Code to JS+HTML+CSS oder something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it, at least not that would produce something worth while.
You should have an API and would need to create a new web based client that calls the API the same way your app does.
The big reason why I really doubt there will be a tool to convert a native app to a PWA is you need to architect the client so you leverage the service worker and I doubt there would be a good way to determine where logic goes in a translation tool. Plus you would be at the mercy of the tool as to how it does or does not do semantic HTML, clean CSS and don't get me started on JS :)